# How to track "freezing" app, finding its source?

Tags: c#, winforms, networking

I have a server with 3 threads and a threadpool for recieved data processing. The only locks (reader and writer) Im using are for client connection lists.
Sometimes the main form freezes for a second and I cannot find the problem. The form doesnt do any hard work, thats for different threads.
I wanted to ask whather there is not any way how to track this "freezing" down? Any help is very appreciated,thanks!

Comment: language, platform, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a profiler on your app to try and help isolate the problem.

I've been playing around with [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler), it looks like a really good utility and is completely free. It shows you some really useful stats like the time spent in each method. If you are armed with this information it should go a long  way to tracking down your problem.

I haven't tried it on a multi-threaded app yet, so I'm not sure how it handles different threads. But it's worth a shot as (like I said) it's completely free (BSD license) and easy to use.

Comment: No problem. There are a couple of profilers available. This is the best(/only) free one I've found so far...

Answer (score 0):

Is application freezing when you are running it in the Debug mode? 
I have experienced a similar behavior myself and when testing outside VS environment (Debug *and* Release builds) the "hiccups" were gone.

Comment: I tried it only once outside od VS and it was the same, however my friend tried it without "hiccups" - so I will make further investigation. Thank you for remembering me this!

Comment: No bother. I hope you'll nail it quickly.